# How do I install org-drill?

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

- I want to use *org-drill* to do flashcard type training on my
  ubuntu computer as was showcased in a few youtube videos. It is not
  clear to me that it works out of the box in 2019.
- *GNU Emacs 25.2.2* *Org-mode version 8.2.10*
- Followed instructions [[https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-drill.html][orgmode.org::org-drill]] after searching the
  backbone for *org-drill*

  - *contrib/lisp* was not found in the machine using *locate*
  - I appended *(require 'org-drill)* to the end of my *~/.emacs*
    and was greeted with a friendly messsage once I restarted emacs.

    ## +begin_src error

    Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
    ‘/home/theusername/.emacs’: File error: Cannot open load file, No
    such file or directory, org-drill To ensure normal operation, you
    should investigate and remove the cause of the error in your
    initialization file.  Start Emacs with the ‘--debug-init’ option
    to view a complete error backtrace.

    ## +end_src
  - Deleted the require line, restart emacs to try the other
    method. Interactive *(customize-variable org-modules)* -> *[X] C
    drill:*. The echo area tells me there is an error when I click
    *Apply*.

    ## +begin_src *Messages*

    Problems while trying to load feature ‘org-drill’

    ## +end_src

    Using *Apply and Save* appended the symbol *org-drill* to the
    list of things under *org-modules* inside of my *.emacs*. *[X] C
    drill:* is checked once emacs restarts and the function is not in
    the namespace of interactive autocomplete.
- Not sure what to try next.

  - [[https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill/src/default/][Paul Sexton's bitbucket]] The author maintains org-drill on
    Atlassian? It is unclear how this
  - [[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983106/how-to-install-org-drill][Tahir Hassan @ stack overflow 2015]]

  ## +begin_src 2015

  Org-drill in official org-mode repository is out-of-date (2015),
  and seems that might be the best decision to install the top-notch
  version from BitBucket.

  ## +end_src

  - [[https://melpa.org/#/org-drill][org-drill at melpa July 2019]] Maybe I should try getting it from
    melpa? I have never used melpa before.

Comment: To use melpa, you'll need to add the melpa name & url via Customize Option `package-archives` . Try this: 1) Do `M-x` `customize-option` `RET` `package-archives` `RET`. 2) Click `INS` button then enter `melpa` in `Archive name:` field & `https://melpa.org/packages/` in the `URL or directory name:` field. 3) Click `Apply and Save` button. 4) Do `M-x` `package-list-packages` `RET`. 5) Search for `org-drill`. 6) Click `org-drill` link. 7) Click `Install` button.

Comment: @Melioratus Thanks for that help. Melpa works. Nearly have it working. Going to tinker more to clarify next step.